# How to unhide navigationView menuItem?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code for updating my UI when firebase user changed

```
fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?){
        if(user == null){
            emailText.text = resources.getString(R.string.email_placeholder)
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_in).isVisible = true
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_up).isVisible = true
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_out).isVisible = false
        }else{
            emailText.text = user.email
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_in).isVisible = false
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_up).isVisible = false
            binding.navigationMainView.menu.findItem(R.id.sign_out).isVisible = true
        }
    }
```

This fun is called every time i log in / log out

But it can unhide only sign_out item once, and, after all my menu is empty.
So, if i have no logged in user when application starts, it looks like:

[Before log in / registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE0S3.png)

[After log in / registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njzAS.png)

[After log out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8sDW.png)

And if i have logged in user, when application starts it looks like 2nd picture -> 3rd picture

How can i fix this, and unhide it?

Comment: taking a wild guess here but perhaps you need to call something like `navigationMainView.invalidate()`

Comment: I tried, it doesn' work, and it is strange, because when i rotate screen and activity restarts it's unhide my items